# NameError: uninitialized constant ControllerName after adding routing namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using `rspec-rails (3.7.1)` with `rails (5.1.4)`

All the tests run successfully, but after adding namespace to `routes.rb` file, I got this error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/stores_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
RSpec.describe StoresController, type: :controller do

NameError:
  uninitialized constant StoresController
```

and this is my `routes.rb` file:

```
namespace 'api' do
 namespace 'v1' do
  resources :stores
 end
end
```

where my `stores_controller_spec.rb` is

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe StoresController, type: :controller do
 let(:store) { FactoryBot.create(:store) }

 describe "GET index" do
     it 'has a 200 status code' do
         request.headers.merge!(auth_headers)
         get :index
         expect(response.status).to eq(200)
     end
 end
end
```

Comment: Your controller might be `Api::V1::StoresController`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I tried this 2 minutes ago, it worked!
Please retype your comment as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a controller route namespace like

```
api/v1/stores
```

then Rails expects the controller to be named

```
Api::V1::StoresController
```

and to be located in a file named

```
app/controllers/api/v1/stores_controller.rb
```

Comment: could you please tell me why I get this error even after adding `Api::V1::StoresController` to Rspec file

`Failure/Error: render json: @store, status: :created, location: @store
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `store_url' for #<Api::V1::StoresController:0x007f9a5438c818>`

Comment: Because when you namespace routes then their method names change too. I guess now you need to use `api_v1_store_url` instead of just `store_url`. Use `rails routes` on the command line to see all routes and their names.

Comment: Thanks man, but I think you misunderstood me, all the methods worked fine without adding anything to them in rspec file, but the create test got this error, where the test is `describe "Post#create" do
        it 'creates a new store' do
            post :create, params: { store: attributes_for(:store, vendor_id: vendor.id, district_id: district.id) }
            expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
        end
    end`

Comment: That test probably fails because the code uses `store_url` somewhere (likely in the `to_json` implementation). I suggest to open a new question and add all relevant code and the full stacktrace to that question if you do not find it yourself. Because it is hard to share code fragments in comments.

Comment: I'll do my search and if I didn't get anything, I'll open a new question, thanks mate! :)

Comment: when I remove `location: @store` from `render json: @store, status: :created, location: @store` in create method in StoresController the test pass.
And as I read time ago that `location` option is used to redirect to a new resource as part of processing the current request.
So I think the create method will be fine with out it, right now!

Comment: Yes sure, now I see. `location: @store` is basically the short version of `location: store_url(@store)`. But now you need to use the long URL version because of the namespace (Rails cannot build that automatically). Just use: `location: api_v1_store_url(@store)`

Comment: Thanks again mate, but as I read it won't hurt, if I remove it at all!